# plot with tikz/pgf from external txt file with one X axis and several Y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am a very beginner of Tikz/pgf. I have searched quite long but didn't found the answer. How could I plot from an external txt or dat file that with one X value and several Y values? For example, the external txt file could be like this,

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you searched this site? This question seems like it could answer your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100712/plotting-functions-with-parameters-from-an-external-file-using-gnuplot-pgfplots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy using `y index` with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
x y1 y2 y3 y4
0   3   4  13   14
1   5   6  15   16
2   2   3  12   13
3   4   8  14   18
4   6   9  26   19
5   8   1  18   11
6   10  2  12  12
}\mytable
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x index=0, y index=1]{\mytable};
\addplot table [x index=0, y index=2]{\mytable};
\addplot table [x index=0, y index=3]{\mytable};
\addplot table [x index=0, y index=4]{\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have valid column names you can simply use

```
\addplot table [y=y1]{\mytable};
\addplot table [y=y2]{\mytable};
\addplot table [y=y3]{\mytable};
\addplot table [y=y4]{\mytable};
```

Comment: Why `y index`? Columns have pretty legal names.

Comment: @percusse Just to be more general!..

Comment: @percusse OK, I edited.

Comment: @HarishKumar thank you so much! Another question is how can I read the external txt file. I would like to draw directly from the txt file not to copy them to tex editor.

Comment: @iori266 Hi. Glad it was useful. Please remember that you can upvote  and accept the answers. For any clarifications, please refer: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Comment: @HarishKumar yes, I have accepted it. But could you answer me about the question that how can I import the data from external .txt or .dat files?

Comment: @iori266 `\pgfplotstableread{mydata.txt}\mytable` where `mydata.txt` is your data file in the same folder.